# Using "div" as a css selector

Tags: html, css

I have a document structure that is similar across multiple pages.

HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <div>
            <img src=""/>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Currently, there is a border around all img elements. The client would like me to remove the border from around the image, because not all images are the same size and they want a uniform look with the borders. I noticed that there was a div wrapping the images, but the div does not have an id or class. How can I select this div in my css?

Thanks

Comment: I don't know of a way to select the div tags in relation to the img tags; css rules only go one direction. You can do it with JQuery however.

Comment: Do the other images have the same consistent pattern? i.e. are the divs the same for other images too?

Comment: is there any other class nested above this <img, or is this the only <ul> tag on the page ?

Comment: What is the CSS code that is applying the border? Where is the border coming from? You should include that in the question as it is relevant information.

Comment: If there is no more requirements, I'd say that the question is answered, right? ;)

Answer (score 7):

For instance using

```
ul>li>div {
    border: 1px solid blue;
    margin: 5px;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

From my point of view, this is the best way to avoid HTML manipulation.

However, if the structure ul>li>div is repeated elsewhere, this can be ambiguous.

Answer (score 1):

Give it a class or ID... Then make the CSS for it.

Comment: I was trying to avoid to this, because I would then have to alter the html over multiple pages.

Answer (score 1):

If there’s no context *anywhere*, your recourse is to select it by the structure (as least specific as possible, if you like); for example,

```
li > div > img
```

But there usually *is* some kind of context. If your `<li>` had a class, for example, you could do:

```
li.contains-image > div > img
```

Or just

```
li.contains-image img
```

if there’s no other image. Does it or one of its parents have a sibling that identifies it somehow? Use one of the sibling combinators!

```
li.before-the-one-that-contains-the-image + li img
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you only have these set or cascade of element in the page you can use

```
<style>
ul li div {
    border: 1px solid red;
}
</style>
```

Otherwise this will add a border on all element matching on the page.

Best is to use an Id or a class on the element.

Comment: ul > li > div is more efficient, given that we don't know the bigger context of the HTML structure.